# is it bad practice to call a function from within an if condition?

Tags: c

hello< I am working on my first solo project in C and I have a bunch of sanity checks which call functions that return a bool. My question is it bad practice to call the the function from within the if condition or should I assign it's return value to a bool variable then use that variable in the condition. I'm teaching myself how to code and I am trying not pick up any bad habits. Below is a code example.

```
// This function checks user input for allowed operation 
// MAX_OPERATIONS is a macro that defines the max number of operations allowed
bool check_operation(char *n, char **ops)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_OPERATIONS; i++)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(n, ops[i]) == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// In main I call it like this
// operations_arr is an array of pointers that stores the operations 
// allowed in string format 
if (!check_operation(argv[1], operations_arr))
{
    error_message();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing inherently bad about that. If you don't need the result value except for checking this condition, there is no need to store it.

Comment: This is a bit different when it comes to conditions of loops. Any function in such a condition is called for each iteration of the loop. If the result cannot change during the loop, you should avoid calling it again and again and instead use the stored result in the loop condition.

Comment: Thank you @Gerhardh and yes their only purpose is to check that condition.

Comment: Both are essentially the same thing, so you shouldn't bother for best practices while learning. @Gerhardh explained it well about conditions to decide when to use what.

Comment: Multiple returns hidden in the insides of a larger function can make the workings of the function non obvious but generally at that time there will be other code smells as well.

Comment: If you are afraid that you may be picking up bad programming practices, then you may want to post working code on [codereview.se] and other people will then tell you what can be improved on your coding style. The main difference between Stack Overflow and Code Review is that Stack Overflow is for asking specific questions, whereas Code Review allows answerers to point out anything in the code that they consider worth improving. See this link for further information: [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/235181)

Comment: It may be questionable to call a function from within a loop's termination condition, since that means it's called repeatedly at every iteration. But there's certainly no problem with calling functions from an if condition.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thanks a bunch that what is definitely something I surely need and I will look into that.

Comment: According to [MISRA 2004 - Guidelines for the use of the C language in critical systems - M14.7.2 Rule 14.7](https://help.blueproddoc.com/rationaltest/rationaltestrealtime/8.3.1/com.ibm.rational.testrt.studio.doc/topics/r_misra_rules.html) _The return keyword should not be used in a conditional block._

Comment: Just as an explanation for OP of the previous comment: The [MISRA C guidelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) are primarily for programs where reliability is especially important, such as in cars or in medical equipment. If you want to only write "normal" software, then, in my opinion, you should not try to follow these guidelines. However, some programmers also consider MISRA good programming style for "normal" programs.

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel Thanks for the info, and I think that I will just assign it to a variable instead, it's only one line of code and as others pointed out it does make the code easier to read. I tried looking at it as if I wasn't the one who wrote it and I can see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it. Though many C functions involve checking the result of parameters rather than the returned value and then you have no other option but to call the function on a line of its own.

Also, this is a common scenario:

```
result_t result = func();

if(result == ERR1)
  ...
else if(result == ERR2)
  ...
```

Here you can obviously *not* write

```
if(func() == ERR1)
  ...
else if(func() == ERR2)
  ...
```

Because then you end up calling the function twice, which is inefficient, but could also give different results.

As for using return from a function as a way to quickly stop executing and go directly to the error handler, it's actually likely the best way of doing so in C. Other alternatives are using messy boolean flags in the loop, or the "on error goto" pattern (which is usually OK but comes with the mandatory, tiresome "goto considered harmful" debate).

As for picking up bad habits: not using *const correctness* of read-only parameters is a bad habit.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about that until just now. I really appreciate that, I will look deeper into the concept but the gist that I got from my short research is that you should use const for parameters that you don't want changed. is this what you referring to?

Comment: But you could also write `switch(func()) {case ERR1: ... case ERR2: ...}`

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with it as such, but I'd argue it's better to assign it to a variable because by doing so you're writing *explicit* code.

Explicit code is easier to read and also easier to maintain. Right now you're returning a `bool`, but imagine in future you change your function to return an `int` in order to pass more information, then you'd possibly want to add more checks. Also, by assigning its value to an explicitly typed variable you're making it easier for compiler to do some basic type checking to guard you from errors that might arise from changing the return type of the function.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense my project still small enough that making the change won't be too difficult thanks for the input.